# How to add Pico CSS to your global scss stylesheet in Angular?

Tags: angular, sass

I just created a new Angular 17 project with SCSS as the stylesheet format and I want to use Pico CSS in my project.

The [Pico CSS documentation](https://picocss.com/docs) tells me do it like this:

First, install Pico CSS.

```bash
npm install @picocss/pico
```

Then, import it in your SCSS file with [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/).

```scss
@use "pico";
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
✘ [ERROR] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @use "pico";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles.scss 3:1  root stylesheet [plugin angular-sass]

    angular:styles/global:styles:1:8:
      1 │ @import 'src/styles.scss';
        ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the correct way to add Pico CSS to my global `styles.scss` in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `@use "pico"`, put `@use "@picocss/pico/scss"` in your `styles.scss`.

```scss
/* styles.scss */
@use "@picocss/pico/scss";
```